# Passing props from page layout through parent slot into child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have a `Card` component that I'd like to inherit a `title` value from the `<Card />` tag's `title` property defined within the parent layout after passing through a `<Cards></Cards>` component's slot.

Card:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    {{ title }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Component from 'nuxt-class-component'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class extends Vue {
  @Prop() title: string
}
</script>
```

Cards:

```
<template>
  <div class="cards">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

Page:

```
<template>
  <Cards>
    <Card :title="ABC" />
  </Cards>
</template>
```

I'm not quite sure how to reference the `title` property.  How is this written in Vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by defining a `title` property in the `Card` component:

Card:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    {{ title }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['title']
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, I do have a `title` property defined in the `Card` component, although I might be defining the incorrectly with  `vue-property-decorator`.  (Updated question to show this typescript code.)  EDIT: Got it.  I had to replace `<Card :title="ABC" />` with `<Card title="ABC" />`